# ASP Connection String

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, adodb

I am at the end of my nerves trying to find this.

I am in progress of migrating SQL 2005 DB's to 2012 and I cannot find the connection string in the websites code.  Its an old ASP page and the only ref to the connection string is at the top of each page with the following.

```
Set OBJdbConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
OBJdbConnection.Open Application("ITRC_ConnectionString")
```

This website is contained within an APPS folder and within the apps folder is a page called appvars.asp.  All the other websites in the APPS folder use this page for their connection string and therefore I can easily migrate these but this one chuffing website isn't listed.

Anyway my question is where are the places I should look to find this connection string.  There must be standards or something I can look for that will tell me.

Comment: Can you search through project files for `Application("ITRC_ConnectionString") =` ?

Comment: Is there a [`Global.asa` file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525316%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)?

Comment: As Richard suggests, look for Global.asa - the fact that it is application variable points to it being there

Comment: Perhaps <ctrl><shift>F ... global search on solution will reveal the loacation ...

Comment: Probably it is stored in the registry?  I remember articles that suggested this practice back in the days ;)

Comment: @stare no, it's not related to registry.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I hate to admit this we have 2 webservers and the site I was looking at was inactive doh!!!  I found the correct site which was re-done in asp.net and repointed the connection string.